# read iphone sms messages?

Tags: iphone

is there a possibility to read received SMS messages ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can.
The sms messages are stored in a Sqlite db file.

Here's some information on howto read and get those files.

[read and save sms](http://menoob.com/2008/12/04/how-to-save-and-read-your-iphone-text-messages-on-your-computer/)

[iphone backups](http://www.tuaw.com/2007/08/22/more-on-iphone-backups/)

Comment: how about code wise, accessing the SMS messages from app?
To explain: 
I have my bank send me SMS messages with my current balance and I would like to be able to access that message and create a graph from that info.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656723/iphone-app-reading-sms

Comment: Code wise would be possible as long as you are able to access the file you need to read the data from. The problem will be to extract the info you need from the message like your currency. Steve Lazaridis
Arren't those database files protected by an encryption?

Comment: Hi @NccWarp9 did you get around to doing what you started off with?

Comment: Sadly no, in the meantime I was distracted with other projects and this one fell of the radar.