# iPhone application – reading SMS

Tags: ios4

I need to develop an iPhone application which needs to read the incoming SMS received by the user, manipulate the text, and then display it in the application.

Could someone clarify whether it is possible to read the SMS received within our application development?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Intercepting/reading incoming SMS is not possible on iOS (for privacy reasons).

Comment: Yes it is possible to intercept SMS ... when the phone is jailbreaked.

Comment: i wan to read SMS but my device is not Jailbreak. I dont want to upload that app to App Store so it is possible or not ?

Comment: My Device is jailbreak, but still I can't access this sms.db file. It's required root permission. How can I give a root permission.

Comment: @mohit : the easiest way is to give your app setuid root when installing it.  Every time the user will start it, it will execute with root privileges.

Comment: @Mads Mobaek, Do you have any links to official documentation by Apple on this? I couldn't find any

Comment: @Mads, i know its been i while but is it now possible to read incoming sms's on iphone?

Answer (score 14):

It is only possible when the phone is Jailbreaked.
There are many tools to jailbreak your phone.

Once Jailbreaked, an application cal open the SQLite database at

```
/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db
```

and read the `message` table.

It contains, the date/time at which the message was received, the sender/recipient phone number and even the clear text of the message.

Answer (score 6):

***UPDATE***

From iOS 12 Apple will allow the support to read One Time Code(OTP - One Time Password) which you will get in the iPhone device.

iOS supports Password AutoFill on **UITextField, UITextView, and any custom view that adopts the UITextInput protocol**. System keyboard set the textContentType on it to **.oneTimeCode**

**1) Using Code**

`singleFactorCodeTextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode`

**2) Using Storyboard/XIB**

> Select `UITextField`/`UITextView` in `storyboard/XIB` click Click on Attribute
>   inspector. Go to text input trait, click to Content type and select
>   one time code and done.

The operating system will detect verification codes from Messages automatically with this `UITextContentType` set.

> Warning
>
> If you use a custom input view for a security code input text field,
>   iOS cannot display the necessary AutoFill UI.

[image: WWDC 2018 iPhoneX Device]

For more information, you can check it on the Apple developer [**oneTimeCode**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextcontenttype/2980930-onetimecode)

And also review [**WWDC 2018 Session 204 - Automatic Strong Passwords and Security Code AutoFill**](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/204/) and jump to **24:28** for automatic pre-fill the OTP.