# Access Inbox SMS programmatically (For Enterprise account app) without JailBreak and don't want to upload on AppStore

Tags: ios, objective-c, sms, message, inbox

I am developing one Application for `**Enterprise Account**` So we don't need to upload the app on `App Store`. So **i can use `private API` on my app without any restriction.**

**i want to read inbox SMS from the `Application`**. I know it is possible in `JailBreak`.
device.

But My device is not JaiBreak and i want to implement that without JailBreak device.

Is it possible or not ?

Comment: Surprisingly, enterprise apps can do nothing that store apps can't also do https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev21218dfd6

Answer (score 2):

Intercepting/reading incoming SMS is not possible on iOS (for privacy reasons).

Related post : [iphone app reading sms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656723/iphone-app-reading-sms)