# How to Make Application which Store Sent and Received Messages in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am new in iPhone and I don't know much about iPhone Technology. I Searched on Stack Overflow but not got any proper solution regarding my Query.

What I need is, I want to Create One Application for iPhone3 as well as iPhone4 WHICH ALLOWS USERS TO VIEW THEIR EXISTING TEXT MESSAGES(only SENT and RECEIVED) FROM "MESSAGE"[of iPhone menu] through a DIFFERENT SCREEN COLOR and BRIGHTNESS SETTING.

Please give me some Suggestion/Helpful Link or any Hint Regard my query. How I start To Code My Application. THANKYOU ALL

Regard,

Tauseef

Comment: do you want to access the SMS database of iphone Messages app?

Comment: i dont think you can access the /var/root/Library/SMS/sms.db , not sure though but AFAIK, app is only  have access to its own sandbox directory. I would love to make an SPY app for my girlfriend if we can access that database :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's possible to read stored messages but you'll also gona have to learn something about SQlite.

Take a look at the links here (the accepted answer and link in the comments): [read iphone sms messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640020/read-iphone-sms-messages)

**But this will work only on jail-broken iPhones and certainly will not be approved for App Store.**

You'll find the location of database in sebsto's answer to this question: [iphone app reading sms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656723/iphone-app-reading-sms)

Comment: THANK YOU ALL VERY MUCH FOR HELP ... GOOD WISHES

Comment: @Tauseef: you're welcome! And yes, to access this database iPhone has to be jailbraked - it's because this functionality could be abused (app could for example read the messages and send them to remote locationm which is a clear breach of user's privacy)