# Access device messages in application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can we read our device inbox message in our app? I have to read all messages which i have in my device message inbox.

Thanks

Comment: Hi all i found solution and now i can send and receive message when my app in offline mode. I am using CTMessage but now problem is that with this we can't upload our app on app store they will reject app.Any one   know public api to do this. On app store so many apps uploaded one is "Find my iphone"

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to access emails or SMS messages? If so, there's no way to do that.  You don't have access to that kind of personal user data using the iOS SDK. Just think about the controversy that UDID's are causing right now, and consider what would happen if a third party app had that kind of access.

Comment: dude we can access incoming message and can send also. With CTMessage but now problem is that we cant upload our app with this. Apple will reject this.

Comment: When I say iOS SDK, I'm talking about public frameworks, i.e. things that will not get your app rejected, which I judged from the tone of the question was his intent.  Sorry if I upset you

Answer (score 0):

You can access messages only on **jailbroken device**.

Your app will most definetly **not be approved for App Store**.

If you're still interested, see the accepted answer on [How to Make Application which Store Sent and Received Messages in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666201/how-to-make-application-which-store-sent-and-received-messages-in-iphone/9666281#9666281)