# How to get inbox all SMS on iphonse sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [read iphone sms messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640020/read-iphone-sms-messages)

I have following question related to get sms.

1. I want to get All SMS Text, sender number, date.
2. How can i send sms through my app?
3. Afterward i want to upload app on app store, so will apple allow me to upload app for doing above tasks?
   Kindly help me on these issues and also share with me helping materiel or tutorial relevant to this tasks. Thanks in Advance :).

Comment: as other said, for app that's ment for App Store it's not possible. If you're still curious you can take a look at answers here: stackoverflow.com/questions/640020/read-iphone-sms-messages, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656723/iphone-app-reading-sms

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Not possible.
2. Check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)
3. For SMS sending through application allowed but for accessing inbox for sms/email not allowed.

Answer (score 6):

As of iOS 4, you can't get access to SMS data for reading, as there are serious privacy concerns.

And Apple wouldn't allow an app onto the store that does this.

[Here's a related question & answer with more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3207977/981049).

Answer (score -1):

It is possible if you have a jailbroken device.
You may use jailcoder to fake code signing and then move your app to /Applications folder.
This way you can access to any database in your iOS device jailbroken.
Obviously Apple deny you app but not in Cydia.