# iOS: Access to root directory in a jailbroken iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, jailbreak

Ok, I used [jailcoder.com](http://jailcoder.com/) to patch my xcode project in order to run my app in a jailbroken iOS device and it works. But still I need list some others files located at root folder. I saw some applications that do that but didn´t find the way to accomplish It.

Maybe there's a possibility to run code as root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered here in a similar question [How to get inbox all SMS on iphonse sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223232/how-to-get-inbox-all-sms-on-iphonse-sdk/12708436#12708436)

It is possible if you have a jailbroken device. You may use jailcoder to fake code signing and then move your app to /Applications folder. This way you can access to any database in your iOS device jailbroken.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly *which* files you need to access, and what permissions they currently have.

Normal apps run as user `mobile`.  If you do need to run your app as user `root`, then [here is one way to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8796556/119114).