# reading / parsing SMS from inbox WITH user permission IOS

Tags: ios, permissions, sms, inbox

I'm looking to access the SMS inbox from within an app. This is what I currently understand -

1. The standard SDK does NOT allow access to the sms db due to privacy reasons
   [iphone app reading sms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656723/iphone-app-reading-sms) 
   and [How to programmatically send SMS on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848/how-to-programmatically-send-sms-on-the-iphone)
2. The app must not be running in the background due to privacy reasons
3. An application cannot access another application's data as each app runs within its sandbox
4. It's possible to access the contact list though (Whatsapp, e.g.)
   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/chapter_1_section_1.html
5. It is / maybe possible to do this on a jailbroken iPhone
   [How to get inbox all SMS on iphonse sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223232/how-to-get-inbox-all-sms-on-iphonse-sdk)

My questions are (in the context of a non-jailbreak phone) -

1. Is it possible to access messages from the SMS inbox AFTER explicit user permission in the app?
2. Is it possible to ask the user to grant access to SMS messages from select users (listed), from within the app
3. Is there some workaround to getting my app to read these messages from select users, with user permission from within the app?

Thanks a ton!
Max

Answer (score 12):

Your understanding of items 1-5 is correct.

To answer your questions:

1. No. There is no API for asking the user for permission to access their SMS, and no public API/approved methods to access the SMS.
2. No.
3. No.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: Even if you manage to read the SMS inbox, Apple will reject your since it is not allowed.

Comment: guess bad news is better than no news so thanks! is there anything different about the Message app though, because quite a few apps access contacts (e.g. contacts backup apps etc.) and Calendar accesses Mail. Is it only SMS which is locked in?

Comment: Off the top of my head, it's SMS, iMessage, call, iBook, and email data that's locked in. Pretty much everything else (photos, videos, audio, contacts, calendar events, reminders) has API's that support authorisation from the user and access to data.

Comment: This is excellent news, and I'm kicking myself for not getting on iOS sooner. This is spectacular for privacy.

Comment: Does all of the above still hold true?

Comment: @JosephK. It certainly does.

Comment: As of 2019, and iOS SDK 12, is it still the same?

Comment: @RajPawanGumdal Yes.

Comment: as of jan 2022? still the same?